# Yocto - Linux Image Generation - Remove qemu Support

Tags: linux, yocto, qemu, bitbake

I'm using Yocto v2.4.1 and BitBake v1.36.0. I want to remove qemu and qemu-native (All qemu related thing) from my custom generated Linux Image.

How can i do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: I've searched for questions about Yocto and I've found that many of them are tracked here. You can check the tag yocto mentionned.

Comment: @jww I'm pretty sure this is a valid stackoverflow question. And also I would like to have an answer to this question too

Comment: Search through poky and find the recipes that contain a DEPENDS or RDEPENDS on `nativesdk-qemu`.  There doesn't seem to be any switch to not include it in the SDK so you have to modify the recipes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

qemu-native is not included into final image, as it is built for the host architecture and then used to run some target binaries during the bitbake build.

Target qemu (like anything else) is included into the image because the image recipe says so, or something else pulls it in as a dependency. You need to track that down.

Comment: I'm using a target hardware ZCU102 board from Xilinx. I don't need it. 
Machine already created and I want to create a custom one without qemu Reference machine : https://github.com/Xilinx/meta-xilinx/blob/master/meta-xilinx-bsp/conf/machine/zcu102-zynqmp.conf

Answer (score 0):

In your local.conf file, you can disable the build of qemu with the following statement:

```
RDEPENDS:nativesdk-packagegroup-sdk-host:remove = "nativesdk-qemu nativesdk-qemu-helper"
```